# Javascript - Reuse variables for creating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

Can I reuse a variable that has been used for creating a DOM element?

I have an example:

```
var pauseButtonElement = document.createElement("input");

pauseButtonElement.setAttribute("type", "button");

pauseButtonElement.setAttribute("value", "Pausar autoactualització");

pauseButtonElement.setAttribute("onclick", "pauseGraphicAU();");

document.getElementById("graphicButtons").appendChild(pauseButtonElement);



var maxYValueElement = document.createElement("input");

maxYValueElement.setAttribute("type", "number");

maxYValueElement.setAttribute("required", "");

document.getElementById("graphicButtons").appendChild(maxYValueElement);
```

Can I use a unique variable to create this elements? Or I have to create a variable for each element? I answer it because I don't know if it's a good practice use a unique variable or many in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same variable. That's perfectly fine and generally preferred if you are only going to need the DOM reference for a defined period of time. In many cases, it is preferred to reuse the variable because it allows the JavaScript runtime to release its object reference, allowing memory to be freed up.

The only issue is that you will have lost that DOM reference and so if you want to interact with that element again, you'll have to re-scan the DOM for it.

In the end, it really comes down to the scope you are declaring the variable in and how persistent you want the reference to be.